# Python basemap m.arcgisimage not showing service when saving image but showing when using plt.show

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using tkinter to develop a GUI to create maps using basemap. I use `m.arcgisimage()` to have a better map background. When I use `plt.show()`, it shows the map with the service I selected using `m.arcgisimage()`. However, when I use `plt.savefig()`, it does not show any backgrounds.

My code:

```
try:
    if basemap_service != 'None - blank':
        basemap_selection = basemap_service.strip()
        print("using {}".format(basemap_selection))
        m.arcgisimage(service = basemap_selection, xpixels = resolution)
    else:
        pass
except:
    output_delete_insert(basemap_service + ": HTTP Error. - could not get basemap. Try a different service.")
```

I select the different background methods using a drop-down menu which include all of the basemap services. The "None - blank" tells the program to not plot a basemap background not using `m.arcgisimage()`. When the button in the GUI is selected to save the map, it prints out what is in the `print` statement in the code above.

I'm not sure what to do since it's not giving me the background image that I'm requesting even though the program is going into that `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: When I used `resolution.get()` (I'm using tkinter), it gave it to me as a string, when the `xpixels` argument requires an integer. Because I threw an exception (incorrectly in my case), the program continued and didn't stop. It should be:

```
m.arcgisimage(service = basemap_selection, xpixels = int(resolution))
```